# C# LINQ How to find matching item from one list in another list and check for the property in the other list

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to loop through a list of item, 
find the matching record in another list and 
check a property of that item in the new list is enabled/disabled.
if false, break the looping.

Here is my code.

```
    var isDataPresent = true;

    foreach (var item in listA)
    {
        var dataPresent = listB
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id && 
                                 x.DistributionType == item.DistributionType)
           ?.IsDataPresent;

        if (!dataPresent.GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            isDataPresent = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isDataPresent;
```

Is there a faster/better way to achieve this.

My updated code with JOIN:

```
    var result = listA.Join(listB, 
                            dt => new { dt.Id, dt.DistributionType }, 
                            dp => new { dp.Id, dp.DistributionType },
                            (distType, dataPresent) => new
                            {
                                distType.Id,
                                distType.DistributionType,
                                dataPresent.IsDataPresent
                            });

    if(result.Any(x => x.IsDataPresent == false))
    {
        isDataPresent = false;
    }
```

Comment: The whole idea with Linq is that you do not need to loop over elements anymore. Have a look at _.Join_

Comment: @Robert would you mind give me a sample which solves my issue? i am not joining actually but need to fetch the item in another list.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your use of FirstOrDefault() to Any()
that way, you don't need to make other checks and you only need one variable.

```
var isDataPresent = true;

foreach (var item in listA)
  {
      isDataPresent = listB.Any(x => x.Id == item.Id && 
                                 x.DistributionType == item.DistributionType &&  x.IsDataPresent);

      if (!isDataPresent) 
        break;        
  }

  return isDataPresent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Any` like below.

```
var isDataPresent = !listA.Any(item => !listB
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id && x.DistributionType == item.DistributionType)
                ?.IsDataPresent.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be `.Count()`

```
var countOfA = listA.Count();
var countOfAWithB = listA.Count(a=> listB.Any(b => a.Id == b.Id &&
                                         a.DistributionType == b.DistributionType));

return countOfA == countOfAWithB;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve by join:

```
    var res = (from dp in dataPresent 
    from la in listA
    where dp.DistributionType == la.DistributionType
    select new {
    la.isDataPresent }
    ).ToList()
```

and there are better solution then `join`